# removing item from localstorage causes json sintax error

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm doing something like a to-do list where the items are paths to files. I want to store each item in localStorage and be able to remove them from the list, but I'm having trouble doing so.

Every item has a cross icon by the side to remove itself. When I click the icon I call a function to remove from localStorage and "repaint" the list of items by refreshing the page. It works if I have a single item, but if I have two or more it doesn't work. This is my code to remove:

```
$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function(e){
       var items = JSON.parse(localStorage["items"]);
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     if(items[i].includes($(this).attr("id"))){
       items.splice(i,1);
       break;
     }
  }

localStorage.setItem("items", items);
window.location.reload();
});
```

I don't know the key to the item, but every cross icon  has the name of the item as their id, so I use that as a kind of selector.

As I've said, if I have two or more items and click the cross to remove one, both disappear from the list when the page gets refreshed and I get the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: You need to stringify your items when you set them back on the localStorage

Comment: if I put this line instead of the one before the reload(): localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemsArray)); the item doesn't get removed. They both still appear in the list and localstorage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `itemsArray` != `items` ???

Comment: my bad, now it works changing it to "items". Thanks a lot @Taplar